# Pundit : how to give the possibility to the user to have access either to all the gardens or only to his ownes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, policy, pundit

I'm trying to define 2 possible index for the users, to give them either the possibility to have access to all the published gardens or only to the one they pusblished on their own (2 different pages). I am completely lost when doing it with pundit as it doesn't depend on the status of the user, but only on what he wants to display. Any Idea ?? Thank you :)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :authenticate_user!
include Pundit

  # Pundit: white-list approach.
  after_action :verify_authorized, except: [:index, :my_gardens], unless: :skip_pundit?
  after_action :verify_policy_scoped, only: [:index, :my_gardens], unless: :skip_pundit?

  # Uncomment when you *really understand* Pundit!
  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized
  def user_not_authorized
    flash[:alert] = "You are not authorized to perform this action."
    redirect_to(root_path)
  end

  private

  def skip_pundit?
    devise_controller? || params[:controller] =~ /(^(rails_)?admin)|(^pages$)/
  end
end
```

**garden_controller.rb**

```
class GardensController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_garden, only: [:show, :destroy, :edit, :update ]
  def new
    @garden = Garden.new
    authorize @garden
  end

  def create
    @garden = Garden.new(garden_params)
    authorize @garden

    @garden.user = current_user
# OU :     @garden = current_user.gardens.build(garden_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @garden.save
        format.html { redirect_to @garden, notice: 'Garden was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @garden }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @garden.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def index
      @gardens = policy_scope(Garden)
  end

  def my_gardens
    @gardens = policy_scope(Garden).find(params[user_id: current_user.id])
  end

  def show
    authorize @garden
  end

  def destroy
    authorize @garden

    @garden.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to gardens_url, notice: 'garden was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def edit
    authorize @garden
  end

 def update
  authorize @garden

  respond_to do |format|
    if @garden.update(garden_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @garden, notice: 'Garden was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @garden }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @garden.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

  private

  def garden_params
    params.require(:garden).permit(:title, :details, :surface, :address)
  end

  def set_garden
    @garden = Garden.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**application_policy.rb**

```
class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :record

  def initialize(user, record)
    @user = user
    @record = record
  end

  def index?
    false
  end

  def my_gardens?
    false
  end

  def show?
    scope.where(:id => record.id).exists?
  end

  def create?
    false
  end

  def new?
    create?
  end

  def update?
    false
  end

  def edit?
    update?
  end

  def destroy?
    false
  end

  def scope
    Pundit.policy_scope!(user, record.class)
  end

  class Scope
    attr_reader :user, :scope

    def initialize(user, scope)
      @user = user
      @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      scope
    end
  end
end
```

**garden_policy.rb**

```
class GardenPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      scope.all #>> permet d'afficher tous les restos dans index
    end
  end

  def create?
    true
  end

  def update?
    user_is_the_owner_or_admin?
  end

  def destroy?
    user_is_the_owner_or_admin?
  end

  def index?
    true
  end

  def show
    scope.where(:id => record.id).exists?
  end

  private

  def user_is_the_owner_or_admin?
    user.admin || record.user == user
  end
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "gardens", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "details"
    t.integer "surface"
    t.text "address"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "admin", default: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this simply by creating a separate scope.

```
class GardenPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  # ...
  class MyScope < ApplicationPolicy::Scope
    def resolve
      scope.where(user: user)
    end
  end 
end
```

Use the `policy_scope_class` option to tell Pundit about your custom scope:

```
class GardensController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def my_gardens
    @gardens = policy_scope(Garden, policy_scope_class: GardenPolicy::MyScope)
  end
end
```

Its detailed in [the readme](https://github.com/varvet/pundit#scopes).

Comment: Thanks Max, it seems to be on a good way but returns me this error : "undefined local variable or method `garden_class' for #<GardensController:0x00007f76d21b68e0> Did you mean? garden_url" . I have no ideo how to solve it.. do you? :)